# Physics: Explain reasoning behind already answered?

Tags: physics, energy

can somebody help explain how they arrived at the answer? I'm at lost at where the values -12, -6, and 8 came from and why...

3 charges are arranged at the vertices of a right-angle triangle with Q1 = 4uc = 2Q2 and Q3 = 3uc.

(1) Determine the total potential enegry of the 3charged system.
(2) Determine the work done by an external force to move Q2 from its present position to infinity.

Answered:

(1) Ui = (9*10^9)*[((-12*10^-12)/(3*10^-2)) - ((6*10^-12)/(5*10^-2)) + ((8*10^-12)/4*10^-2))] = -2.88J

(2) Uf = (9*10^9) * ((-12*10^-12)/(3*10^-2)) = -3.60J

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics.

Comment: Better asked on http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How does your answer differ?

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you dropped a minus sign.

Q1 =  4uc
Q2 =  2uc
Q3 = -3uc

Q1*Q2 = 4*2 = 8
Q1*Q3 = 4*(-3) = -12
Q2*Q3 = 2*(-3) = -6